# how to pass a array of values to the template in the yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am using yeoman-generator, which I need to pass a array of value to the template file.
for example I want to pass a array of text values to the template.

```
  install() {
      async app() {
         let array = ['abc','cde','efg'];
           this.fs.copyTpl(
            this.templatePath('base','/abc.ts'),
            this.destinationPath('example/abc.ts'),
            {'array':array}
          );         
      } // app 
  }// install
```

in the .ts file, i define a variable which received the passed array.

```
public options =  <%= array %> ;
```

My expected result is

```
public options =  ['abc','cde','efg'] ;
```

however the resulted output is

```
 public options =  abc,cde,efg ;
```

how would I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

in the index.js, the array variable is showed as

let array = ['abc','cde','efg'];

then in the template file, if you want to show ['abc','cde','efg'] instead of abc,cde,efg, 
all you need to code in the template file is

[<%= array.map(value => `'${value}'`).join(',') %>]

Comment: Can you please add more context to this?